# Do you know why my bubblesort isn't working? [Python]

Tags: python, bubble-sort

I am trying to make a bubblesort in python from scratch, do you know why it is not working? I am getting the error list index out of range.

```
data = [1, 32, 50, 12, 14, 7, 45, 27, 18, 9, 19, 22, 51, 42, 4, 25, 13, 6, 21, 49, 41, 37]

def bubbleSort(alist):
    length = len(alist)
    for i in range(length):
        first = alist[i]
        second = alist[i + 1]
        if first > second:
            a, b = alist.index(first), alist.index(second)
            alist[b], alist[a] = alist[a], alist[b]


    return data

print(bubbleSort(data))
```

Thanks,
Scott

Comment: There's no need to call `alist.index(...` in that line. The indexes are `i` and `i+1`, since you used them earlier. `index` can also fail with duplicates

Comment: Correcting the `index out of range` error won't make this a working bubblesort program. You might want to change your headline.

Answer (score 1):

change your loop to:

```
for i in range(length-1):
```

since you grab alist[i + 1] max i should be 2 less than length of list

Answer (score 1):

Check if you've handled the case for last element.

```
    first = alist[i]
    second = alist[i + 1]
```

The second line uses i+1. So, when i points to the last index of the list, the second element alist[i+1] seems to be out of list index.

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix:

```
data = [1, 32, 50, 12, 14, 7, 45, 27, 18, 9, 19, 22, 51, 42, 4, 25, 13, 6, 21, 49, 41, 37]

def bubbleSort(alist):
    length = len(alist) - 1
    while sorted(alist) != alist:
        for i in range(length):
            first = alist[i]
            second = alist[i + 1]
            if first > second:
                a, b = alist.index(first), alist.index(second)
                alist[b], alist[a] = alist[a], alist[b]


    return data

print(bubbleSort(data))
```

Comment: 1) You put the desired output into the condition of the `while` loop? 2) You sort each time the `alist`, when executing this loop?

Comment: This makes no sense at all.  You're calling an external sort function to determine when to terminate your loop.  Why??  Wouldn't you consider that "cheating"?  And the use of `index` is changing an O(n\*\*2) algorithm into an O(n\*\*3) algorithm.  You haven't implemented bubble sort.  Not even close.

Comment: Actually, given that the call to `sorted` is itself O(n*log(n)), I'd say you've implemented an O(n\*\*2*log(n)) sort which uses the builtin sort function as an integral part of the algorithm.  Why not just return the result of `sorted` directly?